# Using R to save API XML "response" to .xml file

Tags: xml, r, api, xml-parsing

I'm playing with API data from www.onetonline.org. The output is in XML format, but the API does not produce a discrete XML file. Here's a sample call/response:

`> GET("http://services.onetcenter.org/ws/mnm/careers/17-2051.00/report",authenticate("[user]","[pass]"))`

`Response [http://services.onetcenter.org/ws/mnm/careers/17-2051.00/report]`
`Status: 200`
`Content-type: application/vnd.org.onetcenter..srv.onet.services.ws.mnm.career.report+xml`
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<report code="17-2051.00">`
`<career>`
`<code>17-2051.00</code>`
`<title>Civil Engineers</title>`
`<tags bright_outlook="true" green="true" apprenticeship="false" />`
`<also_called>`
`<title>Civil Engineer</title>`
`<title>Engineer</title>`
`</career>`
`</report>`

I'd like to be able to parse this response into a table based on the XML tags, but I can't seem to find a way to create an XML file from this output (I would do it manually, but down the road I will need this function for many more API calls. If I pass this output to an object (e.g., `object <- GET()`), the object class is `response`, and I'm not sure how to handle that. I'm not a novice at R, but I'm just beginning to dabble in http and API calls, so this facet of R is new to me. Also, I apologize if the formatting this post is improper (the code span didn't seem to be working in the preview).

Comment: Just a comment: If that page is asking you to send a username and password over HTTP, I hope those credentials are not at all important. Without HTTPS, they're sent in plain text and visible to everyone between you and the server.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas- I did not know that! Luckily the credentials and API calls are not particularly sensitive- but this was not made clear in the documentation! Definitely an unfortunate omission!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible to test as the url requires authentication, but this is the usual way to extract content from the http response:

```
library("XML")
library("httr")
response <- GET(...)
xml <- xmlInternalTreeParse(content(response,type="text"))
```

Comment: You're brilliant. This worked perfectly. I apologize for my lack of expertise. Thank you for your prompt help!